# jQuery Calendar Application how?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to have text box which

1. User can come to website select date in calendar only on Wed, Thur, Fri . The date time that user can select must be friday of current week only
2. Higlight of current day.
3. How to print out value of variable in jquery?

Here is my coding but i can do only select Friday.

```
$(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    //if only wed thru fri
    if (today.getDay() == 3 || today.getDay() == 4 || today.getDay() == 5) {
        $("#dateInput").datepicker();
    } else {
        //document.write("Pls come again on wed,thru,fri");
        $("#dateInput").error() {
            alert("Pls come again on frid");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you mean but I guess you can assign a variable and then use the variable elsewhere in your code

```
 $(function() {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var dayNo = today.getDay();
    if (dayNo === 3 || dayNo === 4 || dayNo === 5) {
        $("#dateInput").datepicker();
             alert(dayNo);
    } else {
        //document.write("เปิดให้กรอกฟอร์มได้เฉพาะวันพุธถึงศุกร์");
        $("#dateInput").error() {
            alert("กรอฟอร์มเตะบอลได้เฉพาะวันพุธ-ศุกร์ครับ");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: but how to allow user select only friday of current week. if user does not select friday of currentweek. System show error box.

Comment: It would be great if you could post some code, but have a look here to see if it helps http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1088/jquery-datepicker-disable-specific-weekdays

Comment: ้hi bazinga .. from your code almost same as i want. but i still not idea how to allow user select only friday of current week..         can i disable more than 3 day. var daysToDisable = [0,1,2,3,4,6] like this.

Comment: i test with your code by adding disable day left only friday . like this    var daysToDisable = [0,1,2,3,5];                  it still not work. do i have to change from txtDate.ClientID  to dateInput. if i use textbox likethis                          <input type="text" name="dateInput" id="dateInput" />